# How to run Selenium with Geckodriver .Net core on Docker

Tags: docker, selenium, .net-core, geckodriver

I'm trying to use Dockerize .Net core with `Selenium` (Geckodriver).
But, I'm stuck.

My simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
COPY geckodriver ./out
# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

#=========
# Install Firefox (just testing)
#=========
ARG FIREFOX_VERSION=latest
RUN apt-get update -qqy \
  && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install firefox \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/* \
  && wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/firefox.tar.bz2 https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/$FIREFOX_VERSION/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-$FIREFOX_VERSION.tar.bz2 \
  && apt-get -y purge firefox \
  && rm -rf /opt/firefox \
  && tar -C /opt -xjf /tmp/firefox.tar.bz2 \
  && rm /tmp/firefox.tar.bz2 \
  && mv /opt/firefox /opt/firefox-$FIREFOX_VERSION \
  && ln -fs /opt/firefox-$FIREFOX_VERSION/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
#=========
# End install Firefox
#=========



EXPOSE 80/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestSelenium.dll"]
```

But, It's always error:

```
E: Unable to locate package firefox
```

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Comment: did you check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium ?

Comment: I don't want to use `Selenium Grid`.